# html text hiding with paragraph id

Tags: jquery, html, hide, paragraph

For example, I have 3 paragraphs :

```
<p id="txta">AAAAAAAAAAA</p>
<p id="txtb">BBBBBBBBBBB</p>
<p id="txtc">CCCCCCCCCCC</p>
```

And I have a script that hides them except one :

```
$('#buttonc').click(function () {        
        $('#txta').hide();
        $('#txtb').hide();
        $('#txtc').show()
```

Is there anyway I could implement a code so it would automatically hide all paragraphs which ID's INCLUDE "txt" (instead hiding one by one in his own line) and then just show the paragraph I would show? Something like :

```
$('#buttonc').click(function () {        
        $('#*includes*txt').hide();
        $('#txtc').show();
```

Is that possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `wild card` in [**selector**](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/). `*` will searches `any where` in the string, you can use starts with selector if you know that id will start with txt for `startwith` you need `^` instead of `*`

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rajaadil/vgnrJ/)**

```
$('[id*=txt]').hide();
```

Answer (score 2):

[Contains](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-contains-selector/) selector would help you:

```
$('[id*="txt"]').hide();
```

Answer (score 1):

May be you can try my solution
You can change with substring like this:

```
<p id="txt-a">AAAAAAAAAAA</p>
<p id="txt-b">BBBBBBBBBBB</p>
<p id="txt-c">CCCCCCCCCCC</p>
```

and jquery code:

```
$('#buttonc').click(function () {        
    $('[id |="txt"]').hide();
    $('#txt-c').show();
});
```

Good luck